# React - Elements in a list incorrectly receive hover state when a sibling is removed as result of a touch event

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I've logged a bug for this over in the [React repo](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/24187) but it seems to have gone stale.

Essentially what I'm seeing is that if you render a list, e.g.:

```
return (
  <div>{items.map(item => <ItemDisplay key={item} item={item} />)}</div>
)
```

And then you tap an item to delete it, once that element has been removed from the DOM, its sibling receives a hover state.

I suspect what happens is that the actual element you want to remove isn't removed at all, but is just repurposed to display the other elements. So *technically* the element is still "hovered". But in reality it should be removed.

You can reproduce the example [here](https://qggwpt.csb.app/) by opening it with a touch device ( e.g. your phone ).

Answer (score 0):

Try using **react-app-polyfill**:
"This package includes polyfills for various browsers. It includes minimum requirements and commonly used language features used by Create React App projects."

```
npm install react-app-polyfill
```

And this have to be the first line in src/index.js

```
import 'react-app-polyfill/stable';
```

I tried with firefox and chrome from my mobile and everything is working fine..

Comment: Hmm really? Care to share a repro? I just tried adding react-app-polyfill to my above example and the button still displays as if it's being hovered after removing an element.

Comment: I entered to your the project through sandbox. And used the mobile emulator. And the behavior match exactly to the browsers from my mobile.

Comment: As a workaround, you might want to check if the browser is Safari, and do extra logic to change the background again..